# Outlook forgets settings for font colors

Tags: office365, microsoft-outlook-2016

In my company, we are using Office 365. I have a laptop and we have a Citrix environment. I am not a specialist, but I think profiles are not shared across the laptop and the Citrix environment.

My issue is that I change the color of replies to another color than black, that I do in `File -> Options -> Mail -> Stationary and Fonts -> Replying or forwarding messages`.

When I close Outlook and start it again it forgets sometimes the color. It resets it to black. I have not selected a theme or changed anything else.

Q: Why does it reset the color? How can I prevent this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below to reset the default template:

1. Close Word and Outlook
2. Go to C:\Users\es\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
3. Rename Normalemail.dotm to Normalemail.old
4. Open Outlook and change your default font
5. Close and open Outlook again.

Reference: [Default font settings won't hold each time I restart Outlook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/cb9f23c8-170e-4f28-b938-544603637eee/default-font-settings-wont-hold-each-time-i-restart-outlook?forum=outlook)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. It is mixed up again after the reboot.